# FTP command to List only directories. Impossible?

Tags: linux, ftp

How do I perform directory listing but only display directories?

I tried **ls | grep '/'** but it got rejected with the error :
**usage: ls remote-directory local-file**

This is because command line in FTP is different than your usual linux command line, but I was wondering if there is something equivalent in FTP command

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

The FTP protocol does not directly support such a feature. It does, however, allow for a broad interpretation that some servers use to accept things like using `ls`-style arguments (e.g. `LIST -d`, as mentioned by bdk).

Without such a broad interpretation by the server, you are left with retrieving this information from the listing. Unfortunately the standard doesn't provide a fixed format for this either (although it seems most servers use the `ls -l` formatting).

Answer (score 0):

using just ftp itself can be an issue, but if you pipe the output to a shell you'll have less of an issue.

```
 ftp -i myhost.com/yolo/ <<< "ls -1R all_files_list.txt"
```

we can see each listng in that file contains the file permissions signature like "-rwxrwxrw". a little bit of looking and you'll se that all directories start with 'd'

so

```
grep '^d' all_files_list.txt > only_directories_list.txt
```